# Obtain activity history by group by date

Tags: postgresql

```
reminder_user table
====================
ruid    uid from_date   to_date    instructions created_timestamp
1        1  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000
2        1  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000
3        2  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000
4        2  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000
5        2  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000
6        3  1413072000  1413072000  sample      1413072000

reminder_setting table
=======================                 
rsid    ruid    time          postpond_status   time        postpond_time
1        1      1413072000     postpond         1413072000  1413072000
2        1      1413072000     postpond         1413072000  1413072000
3        2      1413072000     postpond         1413072000  1413072000
4        2      1413072000     postpond         1413072000  1413072000


reminder_activity table
========================        
raid    rsid    created_timestamp   status
1         1          1413072000      missed
2         2          1413072000      missed
```

The purpose of above 3 tables are

1. reminder_user table -- stores the reminder setting against a particular user
2. reminder_setting table -- stores the history of each every postpond activity
3. reminder_activity table -- stores each and every activity against a particular reminder setting

i am just struggling get a postgres query to the history of records for past 30 days grouped togther by date available in created_timestamp column in reminder_activity table along with limit. Any help was highly appreciated.

```
Result set expected as below
==============================

Date           Time     instruction
10/12/2014     12:00    sample
               13:00    sample
10/11/2014     10:00    sample
               12:00    sample
               13:00    sample

Date from created_timestamp Column from reminder_activity table
Time from time Column from reminder_setting table
instructions from instructions column of reminder_user table
```

Comment: You have really strange dates and times in your sample data. What types you're using and what's the meaning of those figures? Why not standard `date`, `time` and `timestamp` types?

Comment: Those are stored in timestamp values